# InfoPath: Time field being converted to current time zone

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

I've created an email form using Infopath. (2007) It contains, first name, last name, date, time from and a time to field. I have supervisors enter the information on the form and submit it to our resource management department. The supervisors are in Central time, and the resource management department is in Eastern time. If the supervisor enters 9:00 AM, when the resource department opens the form it says 10:00 AM. Do you know of any way I can correct this? I've played with the time formats to use the ones without the * that says they are tied to the systems time clock but it doesnt seem to help. Thank you for any input you have! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/153/p/63976/244291.aspx#244291

seems like a bug ,  sharepoint server changes the time zone